# Using libraries in a CMake project in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I am working on a small DLL based on an existing cmake project. Now I want to additionally use the libjpeg-library. The libjpeg-project compiles correctly and I select to install the library. When I return to my main project and try to use the library.

My problem is that cmake can't find the libjpeg library. When I try to have CMake check for the library with this command:
`include (${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules/FindJPEG.cmake)`

It returns:
**Could NOT find JPEG (missing: JPEG_LIBRARY)**

How can I force CMake/Visual Studio to find the libary? Just for fun, I copied the lib-file in every single folder of the CMake project with the same result...

Comment: ***It returns: Could NOT find JPEG*** That usually means you need to tell CMake-gui where it is. You may need to look at the finder module to see what exactly it is looking for.

Comment: If you use vcpkg to manage libraries, MSVC's cmake should be able to automatically detect and use them.

Comment: You should also be using `find_package(JPEG)` instead of that include mess.

Comment: When you are starting `cmake`, did you try to add the parameters `-DJPEG_INCLUDE_DIR="C:\path\to\include\of\jpeg\lib"` and `-DJPEG_LIBRARY="C:\path\to\library\of\jpeg\lib\jpeg.lib"` ?